# multiple file upload jquery : getting errors

Tags: jquery, file, uploader

I am using jquery plugin "http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/" for multiple file uploading.

when I upload 2 or 3 files, it working fine but when i upload more than 3, sometime it is working but some time it is giving error.

The error also i am getting different for each time.

1. Missign Token >
2. Empty File Result
3. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: Some code would be helpful, what do you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like there are several different problems with your code. Guess you'll have to debug it.

Comment: my wonder is, sometime it is working fine but other time giving problem

Comment: i tried giving delay in submission. because i gave alert in submit function, then it worked fine . so i though that since alert will take sometime between each submission so it is working fine. so i removed it and gave delay(800.)but it could not helped me